# Install4j SystemInfo.getFreeDiskSpace returns -1

Tags: install4j

I'm getting a return value of "-1" from "getFreeDiskSpace" on our Solaris builds.  I pass it a directory name (actually, context.getInstallationDirectory() ), and I've even tried ensuring that the directory exists prior to starting the install.

Works fine on Linux.

Is it supported on Solaris?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported on Solaris as of install4j 5.1.5.

Comment: Can you add caveats like that to the documentation, so that a lot of time isn't wasted trying to figure out why something isn't working?

Also, it's not obvious to me why supporting Solaris would be difficult for this method - is it just an oversight?

Comment: The documentation says "Retrieves the free disk space for the disk containing the given file on Windows, OS X and Linux.". I've created an issue to add support for Solaris, HP-UX and AIX for this particular method.